# Superfish submenu not displaying

Tags: jquery, css, superfish

I am strugglging with superfish dropdown menu, It is just showing arrow, when hover on it , doesn't show submenu under it , neither in IE(7to 9) nor FF.
I have goggled and tried to change call of the function with many parameter. here is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/superfish.css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // initialise plugins
       jQuery(function () {
          jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
       });
        </script>



<div class="mainmenu clearfix"> <ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled"><li class=""><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=430" class="sf-with-ul">Yrkesmesse 2012<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a><ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=432">Messe i Indre Ryfylke 2012</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=445">Invitasjon til yrkesmessa VILBLIIRYFYLKE, Tau 2012</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=447">Program "Vilbliiryfylke" 2012</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=446">Messekart 2012</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=448">Invitasjon til føresette</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=431">Læring i Næring</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=203">Kontakt oss</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=429">Etablerardag</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=372" class="sf-with-ul">Hospitering<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a><ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=407">Hospitering 9. trinn </a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=381">Hospitering for 10. trinn Ryfylke</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=415">Førebuing og etterarbeid 10. trinn</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=379">Val av utdanningsprogram i web-systemet</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=400">Yrkespraksis </a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=360">Arbeidsplassar</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=359">Yrke </a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=442">Linkar</a></li><li class="sfHover"><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=296" class="sf-with-ul">UTV og PTF<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a><ul style="display: none; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=375">Årshjul karriererettleiing Ryfylke</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=394">Intranett</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=330">WEB-system - Brukarrettleiingar</a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=346">Kurs og Kursmatriell </a></li><li><a href="/default.aspx?MenuId=332">Tips, idear og litteratur</a></li></ul></li></ul></div>
```

Comment: Where's your jQuery reference?

Comment: I have not mentioned jquery refenrence here in code but it solved now and the error was it was using incomaptible jquery refenece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not mentioned jquery refenrence here in code but it solved now and the error was it was using incomaptible jquery refenece.